# Excel based Recommendations

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having a table with 1000s of entries of SKUS in different branches. My problem is that some SKUS are doing well in some branches whereas in other branches they are not moving at all. Due the the size of portfolio it is impossible to manually check where I can move stock if it is not selling in any particular branch. Is there a way to create recommendation in excel based on demand and SOH.

Table will have below columns

Plant,
Material#,
Stock on hand,
Forecast,
Excess stock qty

I am looking for formula that can advise me where to move stock if there is excess qty.[image]

Comment: Post some sample data and your own attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Harun, I have added pic of data. I have tried multiple ways but I am not able to get even close to what I want. Column highlighted is how I want formula to recommend me to move stock from low demand branch to high demand branch.

Comment: What are the rules that decide how much to transfer, where to transfer, or where to order from? Looking at your screenshot, it doesn't really make sense. If you do AK02(10) -> AK01 and AK03(45) -> AK01 and AK03(48) ->, then AK01 ends up with 183 SOH, while the other rows have no excess.

Comment: Hi Stiffing, The rule is to move all excess stock to branch with high demand even if SOH + transfer qty exceeds forecast. It may take 1 or 2 months to clear all excess stock in branch with higher demand.